# PortAudio Device Names Language

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5, portaudio

I'm trying to utilize PortAudio in a Unreal Engine 5 project. Just started learning to use this API.

I encountered a weird problem when looking at the available devices. All device names are in chineese(?). I can't figure out why that is. How do I fix this?

[image: get device info results]

Don't know if this is useful info, but: I'm on Windows 11. My display language is English. My keyboard language is German. And those are the only language packs I have installed.

Comment: looks like a encoding issue to me

Comment: Oh damn.. You might be right. I never had an encoding issue before. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
#include <windows.h>
...
wchar_t wideName[MAX_PATH];
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, deviceInfo->name, -1, wideName, MAX_PATH - 1);
UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("  name: %s"), wideName);
```